# React datepicker and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-datepicker

Currently trying to use React and Typescript with react-datepicker.

I have a simple setup which I want to test, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object
```

Below is the file which uses the `DatePicker` package

```
import * as React from 'react';
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

interface DateConstructor  {
    startDate: Date;
} 

export class DateSelector extends React.Component<{}, DateConstructor > {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            startDate: new Date()
        };
    }

    private handleChange(date) {
        this.setState({
            startDate: date
        });
    }

    public render() {
        const { startDate } = this.state;
        return (
            <DatePicker 
                dateFormat="dd-mm-yyyy"
                selected={startDate} 
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

It seems very strange to me that the `DatePicker` package needs a string or function?

How to resolve this issue?

Full error below

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
invariant
http://localhost:65273/dist/vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:118:15
ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.instantiateReactComponent
http://localhost:65273/dist/vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:20273:23
ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount
http://localhost:65273/dist/vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:29799:22
ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent
http://localhost:65273/dist/vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:29690:21
Object.mountComponent
http://localhost:65273/dist/vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:12868:35
ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount
http://localhost:65273/dist/vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:29803:34
ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent
http://localhost:65273/dist/vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:29690:21
Object.mountComponent
http://localhost:65273/dist/vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:12868:35
ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount
http://localhost:65273/dist/vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:29803:34
ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent
http://localhost:65273/dist/vendor.js?v=OjVxDpV6p_Jfz2P38F_R2lc3pjVsUisUejeIABZq7AE:29690:21
```

Below is the file where I am trying to render the `DateSelector` component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';

import { DataOutputSwitch } from './ComponentLibrary/DataOutputSwitch';
import { DatatypeSelector } from './ComponentLibrary/DatatypeSelector';
import { DateSelector } from './ComponentLibrary/DateSelector';


export class ComponentLibrary extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}> {

    public render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Pair4Insights Component Library</h1>
                <p>This component demonstrates all separate components.</p>
                <div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column'}}>
                    <h3>Data Output Switch</h3>
                    <DataOutputSwitch />
                    <h3>Datattype Selector</h3>
                    <DatatypeSelector datatype="revenue" />
                    <h3>Date Selector</h3>
                    <DateSelector />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the file in which you are using this function?

Comment: Question updated with full file!

Comment: It seems like your `onChange` handler doesn't work correctly. Check if it updates the state, by logging it to the console in `render` method. If it doesn't, use either arrow function or `.bind` in constructor

Comment: I've set the `onChange` to `console.log('test')` to test whether it was the function. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I plugged this component to a working Typescript React application with minor modifications and it works without any problems. So I suspect this problem is caused by some factor other than this component. Does this error go away if you comment out this component and not import it?

For reference' sake, here's the code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

interface DateConstructor  {
    startDate: Date;
} 

export class DateSelector extends React.Component<{}, DateConstructor> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            startDate: new Date()
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    private handleChange(date) {
        console.log('date is here!', date);
        this.setState({
            startDate: date
        });
    }

    public render() {
        const { startDate } = this.state;
        return (
            <DatePicker
                dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
                selected={startDate} 
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

and the import at `App.tsx`:

```
import { DateSelector } from './DateSelector';
```

As you can see, few changes I've made are binding the `handleChange` function and updating the date formatting (at the question code, it's an incorrect input).

[image: recording-datepicker-gif]

I hope this answer have nudged you in the correct direction.

Comment: Hi! Yes when I comment out the rendering of the component the error goes away.

Comment: @Pimmesz Hmm, maybe something wrong with the datepicker package itself in your workplace folder? Have you tried reinstalling everything with `npm ci` (or your preferred package manager equivalent) for example? Outside of that, there are too many possibilities to guess where things can go wrong I think.

Answer (score 1):

Adding date-picker.d.ts file with:

```
declare module "react-datepicker";
```

will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `selected` `prop` expects to get a string as default selected value. You are passing a date object. You can use `useState` hook to maintain the state like:

```
import {useState} from "react";

const YourComponent = () => {
   const [date, setDate] = useState("");

   return (
      <DatePicker 
          dateFormat="DD-MM-YYYY"
          selected={date} 
          onChange={date => setDate(date)}
       />
   );
}
```

Comment: Well even giving selected a value of `null` should be possible. Still get the same error. If I give the date transformed to a `string` I also get the error: `Invalid time value`. 

So selected expects an object.

Comment: By saying error stack i assume that you share some line number reference to investigate

Comment: This is the full error I've received. It doesn't say anything about a specific line. That is what makes this issue extra difficult.

Comment: Can you show me the import of the `DateSelector` where you are using?

Comment: I've added the file where I try to render the `DateSelector` component in the question.